# Scalar User-Defined Function in SQL 2008 Not Being Recognized

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, sql-function

I created the following function in SQL 2008

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udfSetSupplyStatus(@strOrderID nvarchar(16), @intLineNo int, @intOrderQty int, @strPartID nvarchar(16), @strWarehouseID nvarchar(16), @dtAsOfDate datetime, @strCalcMode nvarchar(16))
    RETURNS nvarchar(32)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @strReturnValue nvarchar(32), @intQtyOnHand int, @intQtyOnOrder int, @intQtyPlanned int, @dtWantDate datetime

    IF (@strCalcMode = 'S')
        BEGIN
            SELECT 
                @intQtyOnHand = (pw.available_qty + pw.committed_co + pw.committed_req + pw.committed_ibt + pw.locked_qty),
                @intQtyOnOrder = (pw.expected_po + pw.expected_wo)
            FROM VE_PART_WAREHOUSE as pw
                INNER JOIN VE_PART as p on pw.part_id = p.id
                WHERE pw.part_id = @strPartID
                and pw.warehouse_id = @strWarehouseID
        END

        BEGIN
            select 
                @dtWantDate = WANT_DATE, 
                @intQtyPlanned = ORDER_QTY 
            from VE_PLANNED_ORDER 
            where PART_ID = @strPartID
            AND WAREHOUSE_ID = @strWarehouseID
        END

        IF(@intQtyOnHand >= @intOrderQty)
            SET @strReturnValue = 'InStock'
        ELSE IF(@intQtyOnHand + @intQtyPlanned) >= @intOrderQty
            SET @strReturnValue = 'Expected'
        ELSE
            SET @strReturnValue = 'NoSupply'

    RETURN @strReturnValue
END
```

I can see the function in the Scalar-valued Functions under Programmability in the Database I'm using but when I try to call the function Intellisense doesn't detect my function.

Comment: Have you refreshed the cache of the Intellisense ?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet. I'll update you once I do. Thanks for the tip!